# ScriptC_"name" is not being generated after making a .rs file (in Android Studio with Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, renderscript, build.gradle

I've just started renderscript in Android Studio. When I make a .rs file, both ScriptC_DS class and a .bc file is not being generated. I've read that it's supposed to be auto-generated once the .rs file is saved, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

**DS.rs**

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.DSing)

void root(){

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.DSing"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportMode true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The MainActivity class currently has nothing (aside from auto generated defaults), but when I try to create private ScriptC_DS inside, I get a message saying "Cannot resolve symbol ScriptC_DS."
**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.DSing

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;


public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private ScriptC_DS test;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your RenderScript source located?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer It's located in the folder app/src/main/java/com.example.DS/. In there I have the .rs file and my MainActivity class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem you are having is because the default project layout in Android Studio is different than that of Eclipse.  You could see this from the `app/src/main/java` layout.  The poorly documented piece is that RenderScript (and AIDL) now get their own directories in the source set rather than getting thrown into the Java source.  Move your code to `app/src/main/rs` and Android Studio will build it properly and generate the .bc file asset.

Comment: Pretty late, but is the `app/src/main/rs` supposed to be auto generated? I had to make my own directory labeled "rs" under main to place the .rs file in.

Comment: No, it won't be auto-generated for you like the 'java' directory is.  Same thing with 'aidl' for AIDL defined binder interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Larry's answer is right, all you need to do is

1. add these two settings in your gradle config 

   `renderscriptTargetApi 18
   renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true`
2. create folder for path 

   `/src/main/rs`

rebuild your project, then you can get ScriptC_xxx to use.